# Does Ubuntu 13.04 have a desktop environment built-in?

Tags: 13.04, gnome, 11.04, vnc

I have a VPS on which I'm planning to install Ubuntu 13.04 .. I plan to use VNC to access this VPS. Currently I use 11.04, which is very much outdated now. When I installed 11.04, I had to follow a guide ([here](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1029327)) to first install `ubuntu-desktop` and then install `GNOME`, and then I could get VNC up and running ?

So would I have to manually install this stuff for 13.04 as well ? Or does it come built-in now ? If its still requires manual installation, are there any guides (I'm a n00b at this) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you installed is the -server- version of Ubuntu. That one does not come with a desktop but you can add software onto it (like a desktop) as instructed in that link you posted. It is common to have the server version on a webhost since most only want to use SQL and a webserver (and those do not require a desktop).

If you install the -desktop- version all the things you installed manually would have installed as well (ie. ubuntu-desktop).

VNC is separate though; you still need to install this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A server installation of Ubuntu does not come with a desktop environment, but you can install these afterwards with *apt-get install*.

A desktop edition of Ubuntu 13.04 comes with the desktop environment "Unity", older versions of Ubuntu come with GNOME.